# DoubleTapped event for ListView items in UWP

Tags: .net, xaml, listview, uwp, winui

I want to be able to double tap on listview items. i used **DoubleTapped** event but when i double tap on listview (not items) event is fire, i only want to work with items (not listview itself (panels, borders,...)), in wpf we can simply do this by creating listviewitem style:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick" />
        </Style>
```

but this method not worked in uwp, how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to be able to double tap on listview items. i used DoubleTapped event but when i double tap on listview (not items) event is fire, i only want to work with items (not listview itself (panels, borders,...)),

UWP platform does not support add the `EventSetter`, If you want to add `DoubleTapped` for `ListViewItem`, please add it into `ItemTemplate`.

**For example**

```
<ListView VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid DoubleTapped="Grid_DoubleTapped">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

As the code above, you could listen the  `Grid` `DoubleTapped`, please note we need set ListViewItem `HorizontalContentAlignment` as `Stretch` to make sure the whole item could response double tap.